# Create coalition combinations with Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array that looks like the following:

```
let electionResultsData = [
    ["VVD", "vvd", 20.5, 2504948],
    ["PVDA", "pvda", 19.6, 2340750],
    ["PVV", "pvv", 15.4, 950263],
    ["CDA", "cda", 13.6, 801620],
    ["SP", "sp", 9.8, 909853],
    ["D66", "d66", 6.9, 757091],
    ["GL", "gl", 6.7, 219896],
    ["CU", "cu", 3.2, 294586],
    ["SGP", "sgp", 1.7, 196780],
    ["PVDD", "pvdd", 1.3, 182162],
    ["50PLUS", "50plus", 0.9, 177631],
    ["OVERIG", "overig", 0.2, 51463],
    ["PIRATEN", "piraten", 0.1, 30600],
    ["LP", "lp", 0.1, 3335],
    ["PVDM", "pvdm", 0.1, 3257],
    ["JEZUSLFT", "jezuslft", 0, 0],
    ["ONDRNMR", "ondrnmr", 0, 0],
    ["LOKAAL", "lokaal", 0, 0],
    ["ARTIKEL1", "artikel1", 0, 0],
    ["GEENPEIL", "geenpeil", 0, 0],
    ["VRIJP", "vrijp", 0, 0],
    ["BURGBEW", "burgbew", 0, 0],
    ["FVD", "fvd", 0, 0],
    ["VDP", "vdp", 0, 0],
    ["NIEUWEW", "nieuwew", 0, 0],
    ["DENK", "denk", 0, 0],
    ["STEMNL", "stemnl", 0, 0],
    ["VNL", "vnl", 0, 0]
]
```

The first value in each array is the uppercase name of a political party, the second value is the lowercase name, the third value is the percentage of votes and the fourth value is the number of votes. FYI, these are Dutch political parties.

What I have to do now is make a system that calculates possible coalitions. A coalition between parties can only be achieved if the parties get more than 75 seats (at least 76) in parliament. I've made a loop to loop through the above array with this code:

```
/**
 * Form coalitions of not more than six parties that exceed 75 parliament seats
 */
formCoalitions(electionResultsData) {
    let coalitions = [];
    let maxNumberOfCoalitionParties = 6;

    // Main loop to check all possible coalitions (28 parties * 28 = 784)
    for (let i = 0; i < 784; i ++) {
        let coalitionSeats = 0;
        let partySeats = 0;
        let coalitionParties = [];
        let coalition = [];

        // The inner loop to generate a combination/coalition
        for (let i = 0; i < electionResultsData.length; i++) {
            // Check if a coalition has formed yet
            if (coalitionSeats < 76) {
                partySeats = (150 / 100) * electionResultsData[i][2];
                coalitionSeats += partySeats;
                coalitionParties.push(electionResultsData[i][0]);

                // If coalition has formed
                if (coalitionSeats > 75) {
                    // Push data into a second dimension coalition array
                    coalition[0] = parseInt(coalitionSeats);
                    coalition[1] = coalitionParties;

                    // Check if the generated coalition array already exists
                    let coalitionsStringified = JSON.stringify(coalitions);
                    let coalitionStringified = JSON.stringify(coalition);
                    let coalitionExists = coalitionsStringified.indexOf(coalitionStringified);

                    if (coalitionExists === -1) {
                        coalitions.push(coalition);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Loop through the coalitions (the charts will be drawn here)
    for (let i = 0; i < coalitions.length; i++) {
        console.log(coalitions[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem is, this code only generates one possible coalition, not all the possible coalitions. I need to somehow store combinations that have been generated and run the loop again without generating the same coalition. The loop has to keep doing this until all possible coalitions with not more than six parties have been generated. After that, the loop can stop.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: There is a bit of an [intricate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_the_Netherlands#Seat_assignment) to distribute seats to parties. Do you want to incorporate this? You seem to work with fractional seats now.

Comment: That doesn't have to be incorporated. The way I explained it is the way I was told how to make it (:

Comment: Please don't re-post your questions; our community often sees this as badgering. We'll now have to close your post as a duplicate, and multiple closed questions can lead to a question ban. If you want to draw attention to your question, see [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046)

Comment: Please don't edit the question to be the same as your other. The answer depends on how you asked the question originally

Comment: now you can update the data ... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a search and test if the count is smaller then the max items and for the sum of seats.

```js
function getCombinations(array, sum, max) {

    function fork(i, t) {
        var s = t.reduce(function (r, a) { return r + a[2]; }, 0);
        if (s >= sum) {
            result.push([s, t.map(function (a) { return [a[1], a[2]]; })]);
            return;
        }
        if (i < array.length && t.length < max) {
            fork(i + 1, t.concat([array[i]]));
            fork(i + 1, t);
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

var electionResultsData = [["VVD", "vvd", 50, 2504948], ["PVDA", "pvda", 40, 2340750], ["PVV", "pvv", 35, 950263], ["CDA", "cda", 33, 801620], ["SP", "sp", 29, 909853], ["D66", "d66", 26, 757091], ["GL", "gl", 26, 219896], ["CU", "cu", 23, 294586], ["SGP", "sgp", 21, 196780], ["PVDD", "pvdd", 21, 182162], ["50PLUS", "50plus", 21, 177631], ["OVERIG", "overig", 20, 51463], ["PIRATEN", "piraten", 20, 30600], ["LP", "lp", 16, 3335], ["PVDM", "pvdm", 15, 3257], ["JEZUSLFT", "jezuslft", 14, 0], ["ONDRNMR", "ondrnmr", 14, 0], ["LOKAAL", "lokaal", 13, 0], ["ARTIKEL1", "artikel1", 11, 0], ["GEENPEIL", "geenpeil", 11, 0], ["VRIJP", "vrijp", 9, 0], ["BURGBEW", "burgbew", 9, 0], ["FVD", "fvd", 8, 0], ["VDP", "vdp", 8, 0], ["NIEUWEW", "nieuwew", 6, 0], ["DENK", "denk", 5, 0], ["STEMNL", "stemnl", 4, 0], ["VNL", "vnl", 2, 0]],
    result = getCombinations(electionResultsData, 76, 6);
 
document.getElementById('out').appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4)));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Just a minor remark about the wording: there is no binary search in this answer.

Answer (score 8):

I propose the following. This assumes that the parties are sorted by number of votes.

```
function* coalitionize(data, maxParties) {
  if (maxParties < 1)  return;
  var coalition = Array(maxParties).fill(0),
      fixedSoFar = 0;
  while (coalition[0] < data.length) {
    let actualCoalition = coalition.slice(0, fixedSoFar + 1);
    if (numSeats(data, actualCoalition) > 75) {
      yield actualCoalition.map((i) => data[i]);
      coalition[fixedSoFar]++;
    } else if (fixedSoFar < maxParties - 1) {
      // add a party to the coalition, simply the next party
      fixedSoFar++;
      coalition[fixedSoFar] = coalition[fixedSoFar - 1] + 1;
    } else {
      // cannot add more parties; quit this approach
      fixedSoFar--;
      coalition[fixedSoFar]++;
    }
    // check if we don't try anything stupid
    while (coalition[fixedSoFar] >= data.length) {
      // cannot add more parties; quit this approach
      fixedSoFar--;
      coalition[fixedSoFar]++;
    }
  }
}

function numSeats(data, coalition) {
  return coalition
    .map((i) => data[i][2] * (150 / 100))
    .reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0);
}
```

This uses a [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) to `yield` coalitions that are found as soon as they are found. It simplifies the rest of the code a bit, as coalitions do not need to be stored in an array. [Browser support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-generators) is good, but no support in IE. You can of course change this to use an array if you need.

Note that the number of parties in a coalition is a parameter here, so you can tune this if needed. The global idea is that this function only considers minimal coalitions. That is, when VVD, PVDA and PVV can form a coalition, then those guys plus CDA are also a coalition, but we do not consider those. Now, we start with a single party coalition. If it works, great, report the coalition and move on to the next party. If it does not, add a party to the coalition if we can. If we cannot, remove the last added party and continue trying with the next party.

We can keep track of which parties we are trying when in an array, this is `coalition` in the above `coalitionize` function. The length of the array is the maximum number of parties that can take part in a coalition. Every value is the index in the array of parties, that indicates which party we are trying at the moment for that slot. To keep track of how many parties are actually in the array, we have variable `fixedSoFar`. Technically, you could do without this variable and do a bunch of array operations ([`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)), but this seemed clearer and faster to me.

I have implemented a slightly more complete [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/crn91f5L/) in a fiddle. It reports coalitions that are found as text on the page and shows how many (fractional) seats that coalition has.

**Edit.** If the input data is sorted by number of votes, then the algorithm does not need to consider as many potential coalitions as I initially thought. I have implemented this in an [**updated demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/crn91f5L/1/).

The only change is that the final `else` clause in the outer `while` loop becomes the following.

```
do {
  fixedSoFar--;
  if (fixedSoFar < 0)  return;
    coalition[fixedSoFar]++;
} while ((fixedSoFar === maxParties - 2 &&
    coalition[fixedSoFar] === coalition[fixedSoFar + 1]) ||
    coalition[fixedSoFar] + 1 === coalition[fixedSoFar + 1]);
```

The key insight here is that, when a coalition does not have enough seats to be valid, we can exclude all coalitions that are guaranteed to have even fewer seats because the parties to be considered come only after the parties considered currently.

This makes an enormous difference in number of potential coalitions considered.

Comment: The [meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345236/962603) that is currently happening aside: you have stated a couple of times that my answer does not help you. would you mind explaining why not? I would be happy to update my answer so that it is helpful for you.

Comment: Just [confirmed](https://jsfiddle.net/sgtjgwpt/) that [Nina's code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42674904/962603) gives the same results as the code in this answer. I also set up a [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/finding-coalitions) that shows that, funnily enough, Nina's code performs better on the data in your other question, while my code performs (much) better on the data in this question. Nina's code returns an array while my code works with a generator, so that may change the results. It is interesting to see.

Comment: I guess Nina's code now moved to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42720987/962603).

Comment: Yes that's right. I remember someone's answer to completely crash my browser when I ran it on a larger array than the one posted here. Nina's code runs really fast, hence the reason I chose that one. Interesting to see the difference in performance with different arrays though.